# React radio buttons not setting initial value; only subsequent values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form with 4 radio inputs. I want the component state to be updated with the value of the checked input.

Currently the input is one value behind the checked value (i.e. doesn't start correctly updating the state until the second click).

How can I get it to set the state on the first click?

**component.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Graph extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      option: null
    };
  }

  setOption(value) {
    this.setState({option: value});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <input
        type="radio"
        name="option"
        onChange={(e) => this.setOption('tmax_C')}
        checked={ this.state.option === 'tmax_C' }
        value="tmax_C" />
        <label htmlFor="option">Max Temp.</label>

        <input type="radio"
        name="option"
        onChange={(e) => this.setOption('tmin_C')}
        checked={ this.state.option === 'tmin_C' }
        value="tmin_C" />
        <label htmlFor="option">Min Temp</label>

        <input type="radio"
        name="option"
        onChange={(e) => this.setOption('rain_mm')}
        checked={ this.state.option === 'rain_mm' }
        value="rain_mm" />
        <label htmlFor="option">Rain mm</label>

        <input type="radio"
        name="option"
        onChange={(e) => this.setOption('sunshine_hours')}
        checked={ this.state.option === 'sunshine_hours' }
        value="sunshine_hours" />
        <label htmlFor="option">Sunshine Hours</label>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default Graph;
```

Comment: you need to declare the function `setOption` like this `setOption = (value) => { ... }` otherwise you'll need to bind it in the constructor.

Comment: also I'd like to not use this `onChange={(e) => this.setOption('xxxx')}` inline... it is recommended to use a function instead

Answer (score 0):

setting component state is async. Using a function will update the component right away: `this.setState(() => ({option: value}));`

more info: [react setState docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Per the second part of your question: Another way to make the handlers more functional is to return a handler that sets the passed value:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Graph extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      option: null
    };
  }

  setOption = (value) =>
    this.setState(() => {
      return { option: value };
    });


  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <input
        type="radio"
        name="option"
        onChange={this.setOption('tmax_C')}
        checked={ this.state.option === 'tmax_C' }
        value="tmax_C" />
        <label htmlFor="option">Max Temp.</label>

        <input type="radio"
        name="option"
        onChange={this.setOption('tmin_C')}
        checked={ this.state.option === 'tmin_C' }
        value="tmin_C" />
        <label htmlFor="option">Min Temp</label>

        <input type="radio"
        name="option"
        onChange={this.setOption('rain_mm')}
        checked={ this.state.option === 'rain_mm' }
        value="rain_mm" />
        <label htmlFor="option">Rain mm</label>

        <input type="radio"
        name="option"
        onChange={this.setOption('sunshine_hours')}
        checked={ this.state.option === 'sunshine_hours' }
        value="sunshine_hours" />
        <label htmlFor="option">Sunshine Hours</label>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default Graph;
```

Comment: Sorry, would you mind clarifying what the code should look like now? If I change the function above render to read like that, I get a console error (SyntaxError: Unexpected token) and my linter says "class properties must be methods"

Comment: @EMPenrose he means replace `this.setState({option: value});` with `this.setState(() => ({option: value}));`

Comment: It now reads like this: `setOption(value) {
    this.setState(() => ({option: value}));
  } , ` but I'm getting the same error i.e. null printed first

Comment: I think the error you're getting was because the handler wasn't bound to the correct `this` context. By changing it to an arrow function it gets the correct `this` binding